# Unable to create a personalized unset

Tags: php, variables, unset

I would create my own personalized unset function but it does not work.
Here is an example of code that does not work.

```
<?php
function remove_var($mixedVar)
{
unset($mixedVar);
}
$sExample='Php';
remove_var($sExample);
echo $sExample;
?>
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken , the unset relates to the arg $mixedVar and not to the $sExample var. Take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: You are unsetting the local `$mixedVar` variable. As far as I can tell there is no way to do what you are trying to, short of making `$sExample` global. See the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Answer (score 1):

Your function won't unset `$sExample` because it exists outside of that function. Wonder why don't you use `unset` instead.

```
function remove_var($mixedVar)
{
   unset($mixedVar); // $mixedVar is unset not actual variable
}

$sExample='Php'; // this is outside variable
remove_var($sExample);
echo $sExample;
```

Even if you pass variable by reference, the `unset` won't remove that variable. For example:

```
function remove_var(&$mixedVar)
{
  unset($mixedVar);
}

$sExample='Php';
remove_var($sExample);
echo $sExample; // Php
```

So you should use `unset` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you're passing the argument by value, so what you do to it within `remove_var()` doesn't affect the original variable, outside the function.  To pass by reference instead, change the function declaration as follows:

```
function remove_var(&$mixedVar)
```

However, there's still a quirk using `unset()` this way -- it doesn't work for me, even when the variable is passed by reference.  However, it *does* work if you set the variable to `null` instead, which is mostly equivalent.  When the variable in the function is `unset()`, it removes that reference but leaves the original reference and doesn't change the value.  When you change the value to `null` instead, the references are left alone but the value is obviously changed to `null`.  Since getting the value of an unset variable gives you `null` anyway, that should be effectively equivalent.  So try:

```
function remove_var(&$mixedVar)
{
  $mixedVar = null;
}
```

Comment: That's true but `null` still keeps that reference in memory which defies the purpose of `unset`. The point here is that we should explain to OP that he should use `unset` which does what he is after and thereby avoid unnecessary code or rather such bad practice :)

Comment: I'd figured he wanted to do something else in that function as well, that he hasn't shown -- otherwise there'd be no point in a personalized version.  But I suppose it'd be best just to have a function for that other, unmentioned stuff and call `unset()` *after* anyway.

Comment: I agree with you in that case but guess what a wrong answer has been accepted by OP, funny :)